# Probability of seeing 1-9 in 15 randomly generated digits

Tags: probability, permutations

My calculator has space to display 15 digits, and when I push the RAND button it generates a random digit (0-9) in each of the 15 spaces. I was wondering, when I push the RAND button once, what's the probability of seeing at least one 1, and at least one 2, at least one 3, and so on up to 9?

I thought that first I would find the number of ways to arrange the digits 1-9 in 15 spaces which is P(15,9). So 9 of the spaces are filled and there are 6 spaces left over and to account for the number of possibilities for those 6 spaces you multiply by $10^6$. Then I divide all that by the total number of possibilities which is $10^{15}$. But then I get an answer that's greater than 1 so it's obviously not right. What am I doing wrong? I suspect that I'm counting some permutation too many times, but what is that permutation? Or am I just not using the definition of permutation correctly?

I'm more interested in why my idea was wrong rather than what the correct method really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a slightly peculiar problem in that you ask for the number
of 15-digit strings of zeros up to nines in which all of $1,\ldots,9$
occur, but you don't insist zero occurs.

The number of possibilities where all of $0,1,\ldots,9$ occur is
the number of surjective maps from $\{1,2,\ldots,15\}$ to $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$. This is $10!S(15,10)$ where $S(n,k)$ denotes
a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). Likewise the
number of possibilities with $1,\ldots,9$ appearing but zero doesn't is
$9!S(15,9)$. The probability you seek is
$$\frac{10!S(15,10)+9!S(15,9)}{10^{15}}=0.0703098107712$$
if my calculation is correct.

Comment: I know it's strange to ask for only the probability of seeing 1-9, I was going to try to find the probability of 0-9 myself later once I knew what to do. I'm not sure what surjective maps means, but I guess the takeaway is that trying to use a counting method to find this probability means that I can't just use simple permutations like I originally thought.